# I am searching for the adverbial form of "undefeatable" or a suitable synonym

Tags: synonyms, adverbs, translation

I am translating a text, and I have a sentence that structurally translates into:

> "The noble ideal they have in their sights will enter even the darkest souls and convert *undefeatably* into a charitable reality like every scientific truth"

I do not believe that "undefeatably" is a valid word. Neither is "unconquerably" or "unbeatably"?

I could use "inevitably" but that is not quite the same. The text is about war and peace - not the book, but the concepts - so, a word that relates to defeat in battle would be appropriate.

Comment: 'undefeatably' is a perfectly fine derivative. It says exactly what it means. It appears in the OED with the expected meaning.

Comment: if my 21 years as a native english speaker is anything to go by, you can turn any adjective into an adverb and people shouldn't have any difficulty understanding the meaning you're trying to get across

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps ***unbeatably*** would work better. It carries more validity as a word, and in a sentence with several long words it is less of a mouthful.

Or another possibility might be ***invincibly***. That's a word alright.

Others: - ***indomitably, unassailably***

Answer (score 4):

Try ***inexorably***, the adverb form of *inexorable*,
which [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inexorably) defines as:

> not to be persuaded, moved, or stopped : RELENTLESS
> *inexorable* progress

Answer (score 2):

You could also  try:

> invincibly = in a way that is impossible to defeat or prevent from doing what is intended
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/invincibly)

although I suggest moving away from the battlefield and using:

> unquestionably = in a way that is obvious and impossible to doubt
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unquestionably)

Answer (score 1):

How about

> invincibly

as in

> he kicked the football invincibly.

Here, invincibly modifies kicked and so is an adverb.